# Javascript: indexing set of objects for searching by two properties

Tags: javascript, search, indexing

what datastructure / algorithm should I use for this?

I have a large number of points on a cartesian grid, locations specified by (x, y). I want to have a fast search, returning the set of points (objects) that lie within a given range of x and of y. (A rectangle within the grid).

Perhaps there's a lightweight framework that will do this?

Thanks

Comment: A point-region quadtree?

Answer (score 1):

I would store the points as objects with two attributes: x and y, and a comparative function, which sorts them on one attribute or the other, using the remaining attribute as a tie breaker:

```
function Point(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.compareTo =function(otherPoint){
        if(otherPoint.x != this.x)
            return this.x-otherPoint.x;
        return this.y-otherPoint.y;
    }
}

points[n] = new Point(someX, someY);
```

Then, you can use a sorting algorithm (such as QuickSort - with *O(n log(n))*) to sort them, and a simple insertion sort to keep them sorted as Points come and go.  When you need to use your rectangle select, you can simply do a binary search across them (*O(log(n))*) to find the boundaries of the first attribute(say, `x`), then again across that smaller set to find the boundaries of the secont attribute(say, `y`), and the remaining set will be the ones you're looking for, making your search time (*O(4 log(n)*) worst case, and your your insert time linear(worst case).  Not too shabby, if I do say so myself.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the optimal implementation for the general problem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Higher_dimension

[How to search objects affecting a point in space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500160/how-to-search-objects-affecting-a-point-in-space/16500407#16500407)